# How to add OAuth to an Android app to search tweets

Tags: java, android, json, twitter, oauth

I am a relative newbie to android programming and I am working on an app to search for tweets based on the user's input. I have a program that currently works on APIv1. I have the Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Access Token, Access Token Secret with me. I need a method which just authorizes me to use the Twitter APIv1.1 and then get the tweets with the search term using JSON.

This is my Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.joel.twittersearchactivity">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.joel.twittersearchactivity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView tweetDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tweetDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tweet_txt);
    }


    public void searchTwitter(View view){
        EditText searchTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_edit);
        String searchTerm = searchTxt.getText().toString();
        if(searchTerm.length()>0){
            try{
                String encodedSearch = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "UTF-8");
                String searchURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json"+encodedSearch;
                new GetTweets().execute(searchURL);

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                tweetDisplay.setText("Whoops - something went wrong!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
            tweetDisplay.setText("Enter a search query!");
    }

    private class GetTweets extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... twitterURL) {
            StringBuilder tweetFeedBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String searchURL : twitterURL) {
                HttpClient tweetClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try {
                    HttpGet tweetGet = new HttpGet(searchURL);
                    HttpResponse tweetResponse = tweetClient.execute(tweetGet);
                    StatusLine searchStatus = tweetResponse.getStatusLine();
                    if (searchStatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                        HttpEntity tweetEntity = tweetResponse.getEntity();
                        InputStream tweetContent = tweetEntity.getContent();
                        InputStreamReader tweetInput = new InputStreamReader(tweetContent);
                        BufferedReader tweetReader = new BufferedReader(tweetInput);
                        String lineIn;
                        while ((lineIn = tweetReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            tweetFeedBuilder.append(lineIn);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        tweetDisplay.setText("Whoops - something went wrong!");
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    tweetDisplay.setText("Whoops - something went wrong!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return tweetFeedBuilder.toString();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            StringBuilder tweetResultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray tweetArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int t=0; t<tweetArray.length(); t++) {
                    JSONObject tweetObject = tweetArray.getJSONObject(t);
                    tweetResultBuilder.append(tweetObject.getString("from_user")+": ");
                    tweetResultBuilder.append(tweetObject.get("text")+"\n\n");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                tweetDisplay.setText("Whoops - something went wrong!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(tweetResultBuilder.length()>0)
                tweetDisplay.setText(tweetResultBuilder.toString());
            else
                tweetDisplay.setText("Sorry - no tweets found for your search!");
        }
    }


}
```

I have included the apache library in my gradle and I know it's obsolete but I am following a tutorial and I don't want to change it right now.

Also, I have updated the query URL for JSON as per the Twitter's API documentation.

I run this app as is, and the output is *'Sorry - no tweets found for your search!'* which I believe is due to error code: 215 which is displayed if you query the Twitter API without OAuth.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firstly there's no point in following an outdated tutorial.. Working with deprecated code will only cause problems. Secondly you need to authenticate with the api before getting data. See https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only

Comment: @akash93 the reason I had to work with an outdated tutorial is because I didn't get any new ones. Also, I know I have to authenticate with the API (as stated in my query), my question is how.

Comment: The link I shared has step wise instructions on how to construct the request . Also a google search for `twitter feed android example` gives me this.. https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/overview.html